# How to read only a particular part of a string or a sub-string

Tags: python, cs50

The goal of this project is to open and read a DNA sequences from a text file, e.g if the sub-string is AGATC and then the consecutive sub-string is also, we add to the counter, once the consecutive sub-string is no longer AGATC the aim is to tally it to the highest score in the range, clear the counter and continue searching so as to find the longest consecutive sequence.

```
        str_count = []
        counter = 0
        highest = 0
        # read sequence
    
        with open(argv[2], "r") as seq:
            seqRead = seq.read()
            for i in range(len(seqRead)):
                #search for consecutive AGATC
                if i == 'A' and seqRead[i:i+6] == 'AGATC':
                    while i == 'A' and seqRead[i:i+6] == 'AGATC':
                        counter += 1
                        i = i + 5
                if highest < counter:
                    highest = counter
                    counter = 0
                else:
                    counter = 0
```

Right now the problem I think i am having is I don't think I am comparing the text sequence correctly and thus not reading the correct sequence of letters in the string.

My aim is to track 'i' as a 'A' and then extract sequential 4 letters and compare it to 'AGATC' and then if it matches increase the counter and change 'i' to the letter following the compared, and if it is A repeating until no longer consecutively, and then adding to highest until reaching the end.
This is the im atleast, however when running the debugger I notice that it never enters the first if statement, which leads me to believe the way I am comparing is incorrect.

Sample input:

```
AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCDJFDHFDTTTTCCSSDDSDDGFJFHAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATGJFHJGHJDSHGDKFSAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCDKFDKDFKGJKDFKAGATCkFGJKFDDAGATCDFKJKFJFKDJKAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCKFDHDFKFDHKGHKDFGJFKHDFK
```

Expected output: highest = 30

Due to the fact that the longest consecutive appearance of AGATC is 30.

input:

```
AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG
```

output: highest = 4

Am i mistaken with how to use the seqRead[i:i+6]?

And how could I go about doing this better?

Comment: Can you also provide a sample input? And the expected output? It could be a portion of the file that you're reading.

Comment: Editted with sample and expected

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think your first example has 29 consecutive appearances, rather than 30

Comment: @Kwsswart thank you for providing the sample input. Please see my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `if` before `while` loop is redundant. And you're slicing an incorrect substring, here is the updated and simplified code:

```py
for i in range(len(seqRead)):
    while seqRead[i:i+5] == "AGATC":
        counter += 1
        i += 5
    if counter > highest:
        highest = counter
    counter = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for that i realize was making my code unnecissarily long

Answer (score 0):

Your substring is too long, `seqRead[i:i+6]` will give a string of length 6 characters, rather than 5. That line (and the other line which makes a similar comparison) should be `seqRead[i:i+5]` instead. Also, you were trying to compare your iterator (`i`) to a letter, when I think you meant to compare the letter at the *position* of the iterator in `seqRead` instead. `i == 'A'` should be changed to `seqRead[i] == 'A'`:

```
    str_count = []
    counter = 0
    highest = 0
    # read sequence

    with open(argv[2], "r") as seq:
        seqRead = seq.read()
        for i in range(len(seqRead)):
            #search for consecutive AGATC
            if seqRead[i] == 'A' and seqRead[i:i+5] == 'AGATC':
                while seqRead[i] == 'A' and seqRead[i:i+5] == 'AGATC':
                    counter += 1
                    i = i + 5
            if highest < counter:
                highest = counter
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter = 0
```

Comment: I tried the + 5 at first and it didnt work either thats why i think its something to do with the way i am reading it

Comment: @Kwsswart ah ok, I'll test out with the sample input you provided then

Comment: @Kwsswart I updated my answer, there was another problem

Comment: @Kwsswart no problem and yeah I did at first too haha